# why $x_m$ converges weakly to $x_\infty$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $(X,\|.\|)$ be reflexive Banach space and $Y$ be a closed separable subspace of $X$ $\big((Y ,\|.\|)$is clearly a separable reflexive Banach space$\big)$, then the dual space $Y^*$ of $Y$ is separable. Let $\{y_n^*\}$ be a countable dense subset of $Y^*$.

Let $\{x_m\}$ be a bounded sequence in $X$, such that
$$
\langle y_n^*, x_m\rangle\underset{m}{\to }z_n\qquad \forall n
$$
With $z_n\in\mathbb{R}$.

We suppose that the sequence $\{x_m\}$ has a subsequece $\{x_{m_i}\}$ weakly convergente in $Y$ to an element $x_\infty$. Then
$$
\langle y_n^*, x_\infty\rangle=z_n\qquad \forall n\qquad (*)
$$
Since $\{y_n^*\}$ separates the points of $Y$, it follows from $(*)$ that every limit point of $\{x_m\}$ must equal $x_\infty$.

**My problem**

I don't understand why : we can conclude that $x_m$ converges weakly to $x_\infty$

This result was used in the article **Infinite-Dimentional Extension of a Theorem of Komlos** of *Erik J.Balder*, on pages 186-187. In the context of the article, the auther says that: "$\{s_n(t)\}$ converges weakly to a point $y_t$ in $Y$." But i don't understand why. An idea please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Banach-Alaoglu we know that any norm bounded sequence in a reflexive Banach space has a weakly convergent subsequence. Thus any subsequence of $(x_m)$ must have have a weakly convergent subsequence, which by $(*)$ must have $x_\infty$ as a limit. Thus every subsequence has a further subsequence converging weakly to $x_\infty$, so we must have the original sequence converging weakly to $x_\infty$.

This holds due to the following fact: In any topological space, if any sequence $(x_n)$ satisfies the property that every subsequence contains a convergent subsequence converging to the same limit, then $(x_n)$ itself converges to that limit. This is easy to prove by contradiction.

Comment: The subset is in your context: is it subspace $Y$ or the weak closure of sequence $\{x_m\}$?

Comment: @Jack any weakly closed and norm bounded subset containing $(x_m)$ will do.

Comment: But, according to the Banach-Alaoglu theorem, the condition of convexity on the subset is necessary no?

Comment: @Jack yes indeed we require convexity, which I should have mentioned. This is not a problem for this question though.

Comment: So we take as a subset the closure of convex hull of sequence $\{x_m\}$

Comment: I didn't understand why $x_m$ weakly convergent to $x_\infty$?

Comment: @Jack Yes that subset will do. We are getting a bit track though. The importance is that Banach Alaoglu implies that every bounded subsequence in a reflexive Banach space has a weakly convergent subsequence, and by the OP's arguments we know that they must converge to $x_\infty$.

Comment: Does any subsequence of $\{x_m\}$ converge weakly to $x_\infty$?

Comment: @Jack Please see my edit. Hopefully that clears it up

Comment: @K.Power Your answer is of course completely correct, however the assumption that the topological space is Hausdorff in the fact you use is actually unnecessary. In any topological space, if every subsequence of $x_n$ has a further subsequence converging to $x$ and then $x_n \to x$. Of course, if the space isn't Hausdorff it may converge to some other point as well since limits aren't unique.

Comment: @RhysSteele Yes indeed you are quite right. I just specified Hausdorff to avoid any confusion involving multiple limits with the commenter I was trying to clarify things for. I will edit to remove the Hausdorff part, because you're right it does imply untrue things out of context. Thanks for bringing it up.